# How to count the amount of comparisons in a quick sort algorithm?

Tags: c++

I have the following quick sort algorithm:

```
int quicksort(int data[], size_t n, int &counter)
// Library facilities used: cstdlib
{
    
    size_t pivot_index; // Array index for the pivot element
    size_t n1;          // Number of elements before the pivot element
    size_t n2;          // Number of elements after the pivot element

    if (n > 1)
    {
        // Partition the array, and set the pivot index.
        partition(data, n, pivot_index, counter);
        

        // Compute the sizes of the subarrays.
        n1 = pivot_index;
        n2 = n - n1 - 1;

        // Recursive calls will now sort the subarrays.
        quicksort(data, n1, counter);
        quicksort((data + pivot_index + 1), n2, counter);
    }

    return counter; 
}
void partition(int data[], size_t n, size_t& pivot_index, int &counter){
    
    int pivot = data[0]; 
    size_t too_big_index = 1;
    size_t too_small_index = n - 1;

    while (too_big_index <= too_small_index)
    {
        
        while (++counter && (too_big_index < n) && (data[too_big_index] <= pivot)) too_big_index++;
     
        while (++counter && data[too_small_index] > pivot  ) too_small_index--;
       
        counter++;
        if (too_big_index < too_small_index) swap(data[too_big_index], data[too_small_index]);
    };

    pivot_index = too_small_index;
    data[0] = data[pivot_index];
    data[pivot_index] = pivot;

    
}
```

I have added the three counter increments in the partition function, however the the counter comes out with a value of 32019997 when using a sorted array of 8000 elements, I am using a pivot of the left-most element (I know that gives me a terrible worst-case in terms of sorted array), unless I am incorrect, shouldn't the worst case be n^2 i.e 64000000? So I assume the way I am counting comparisons is wrong, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Maybe your algorithm is doing `n^2 / 2` comparisons.

Comment: Worst case of quicksort is `O(n^2)` which is some `C * n^2`. `C` being 0.5 or so is perfectly valid no? Or have you a reason to believe `C` is 1 in this case?